# JavaScript Variable Outside Function

Tags: javascript, json, http, curl, get

I'm having problems with JavaScript and especially with a variable:

```
var totalrec = {};
        $http.get('url').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                totalrec = data;
                //here it all works
                console.log(data);
                }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               .....
                });
        //here it prints an empty object
        console.log(totalrec);
```

I receive a JSON string from an external server. When I print it to the console.log in the success function it works. But I need arguments from the JSON string outside the function. If I print it to the console.log outside the function it prints an empty object.. Who can help me?

Comment: Your data object is only accessible in the scope of the success function and error function not outside.

Comment: You assigned `data` to `totalrec`. Why do you need `data`?

Comment: Shouldn't you print `totalrec` outside the function?  `data` is only visible wihtin the anonymous success function. But you already put the data in a global var...

Comment: Suggest reading this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Sorry. I meant printing totalrec outside the function.. typo. It also doesn't work if I print totalrec. And i need data since the JSON string is in data, right?